# Related Questions

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

I have some few observations about closed questions

- Some Questions closed as duplicate are not necessary duplicate but have similar title
- Some Questions closed as duplicate contain duplicate links to other Question with no answers , outdated and answers no longer relevant
- Some Question closed as duplicate contain a duplicate link to questions also closed as duplicate ( Have seen chains of to 4 levels)
- It more difficult to reopen a closed question even if its still relevant

I would like to suggest

- Introduction of a related question rather than close as duplicate is the only alternative you can specify URL. A question can simply be assign as related and linked  to others has related questions ?
- The question can sill be closed because probably its too localized but can also be related to so many other question which can be useful
- Even if the question is not closed .. It can sill be related to many other useful Question and Answers

Lastly

I know there is a Related Search at the low right are but am taking about user specific suggestions

Comment: In my experience, wrongful duplicate closings happen *very* rarely. I'm open to being convinced otherwise, but I don't believe there is a problem here

Comment: It really not a problem but rather a suggestion and  increasing the site user experience ... Its also not `wrongful duplicate` but rather its seen as duplication because that is the only option available

Comment: If you post a comment with a link to a related question, it appears on the right under the "Linked" list.

Comment: @Asad how does this solve chain closed duplicate ?

Comment: It doesn't. I was addressing your request that users be able to suggest related questions instead of closing as duplicate.

Comment: @Asad .. I guess that is `100%` sufficient for that ... thanks ... Just trying to see how we can improve the experience

Comment: @Pekka웃 typical example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12891689/php-fastest-way-to-check-presence-of-text-in-many-domains-above-1000 this was said to be duplicate to a question that was closed base on not constructive ....

Comment: @Baba yeah, the closing should have been the other way round (the question you link to had a decent answer)

Comment: I see this all the time ... I am just thinking of a way we can improve this .. rather `close as duplicate` you can `merge or link as related`

Answer (score 2):

I'll just say it: we don't need a new feature for this. If you post a comment with a link to another post it will show up in the "Linked" section in the sidebar (and of course, in the comment itself).

As to your other concerns, sometimes people make mistakes. If you see a post wrongfully closed or with pending close votes, leave a comment or cast a reopen vote. Adding a new feature won't solve that problem. The "reopen vote" review queue usually gets flushed out pretty fast, so it won't go unnoticed.