# Is it ok to link related questions in the comments?

Tags: support, linked-questions

I am not sure if there is an answer here about this. This addresses the issue, but in a different way [Related Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169029/related-questions). I'm not referring to flagging posts as duplicates.

If there are some closely related questions on Stackoverflow, is it ok, good practice, bad practice to provide manually posted links to related posts in the comments?

I've done this in a series of questions I've asked that are related, but not identical and linked them with other similar questions, as I figure it helps people searching.

[What is the difference between null, 0 and nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653937/what-is-the-difference-between-null-0-and-nothing)

Is this something that should be encouraged?

Please advise.

*edit: as noted in the comments by @Richard J. Ross III the links showing up in the related sidebar are not always the best choice for related posts.*

Comment: Please do this! It helps people who are searching for solutions in the future to find posts that are *actually* relevant to what they need (rather than the 'related' sidebar, which is usually hit-or-miss).

Comment: See the related Q here is the FAQ for [se] sites lol

Comment: And who looks at the sidebar anyway? Other than myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, of course it's OK to link to other questions. Encouraged, even. It's even OK to link to questions that were already selected to be in the "related questions" list. That list is generated automatically, and might not really be relevant. When you link to a question manually, you're endorsing that link, letting others know that it wasn't just chosen because the algorithm *thought* it was good.

Even better if you have a few words to say about the link, too, explaining why you think it's related. Link-only comments are as bad as link-only answers.