# Should we have a badge for users pointing out relevant related questions

Tags: feature-request, comments, questions, badge-request

Since pointing out relevant related questions in comments seems to be [positively seen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203653/245125) by the community. I think it's a useful addition to the ones that are automatically linked.

Would it be appropriate to encourage pointing out related questions with a badge?

As an example, you would get points when:

- you are the first to link the question
- your comment gets upvoted n times
- the link get m hits

To be clear, I'm not talking about *duplicates* which should be pointed out for moderation, but related questions.

Comment: How would you measure this? Do we really want 1000 redundant "related" links on each question?

Comment: @DoubleAA we clearly don't want 1000 redundant links. It must be trivial to check if a link has already being posted under the same thread, since it's already detected for the "linked" list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions)

Comment: So a badge for doing what we should be doing, this is like, giving a badge for finding a duplicate (somebody suggest a badge for doing this) recently

Comment: @Ramhound no, my question is not about duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

**Nope**.

Badges are a way of adding more spice to the [gamification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification). When you add this spice, a portion of people inevitably eat the food because of the tasty spice, not the food itself. So we should add the spice when the benefits outweigh the disadvantages, and we should introduce a badge when playing for it is worth it.

In this case, IMO, it's not. For starters, you have no useful way of identifying related questions. [These posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22related%22+%22badge%22+%22appropriate%22) contain the words "badge", "appropriate" and "related"; just like your question. How many of them are relevant?

Comment: The second paragraph illustrates my point, the automatic identification of related questions performs typically worse than people linking question they find relevant.

Comment: It doesn't @Cape. You're saying that linking to something relevant is good behavior. I don't disagree. I disagree with having a new badge for it, since it would make comment moderation impossible. Imagine I posted all of those results as a "related:" comment. Who would've been there to stop me?

Comment: There is nothing to stop you from doing it now. In my post, I suggest compiling the number of times the comment is voted up and times the links are actually accessed to attribute a badge.

Comment: @Cape The voting system isn't that reliable, and a high threshold would mean very few commenters will get the badge. People do a lot of amazing things that they don't get a reward for, and the badges naturally are for activities that are highly common among the members in the site, or very positive actions. Linking to something related isn't any of them. There are way better candidates for badges that are left hanging in the air, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109543/give-a-badge-to-users-who-improve-closed-questions).