# Can I prevent link back(appear in Linked Sidebar) when adding a link to another post?

Tags: support, linked-questions

Frequently I add links to other questions or answers in my posts, providing additional information for a subject.

This link appears on the **Linked Sidebar** of the question, which is ok.

The issue is that the **linked post now contains a link back (appear in its Linked Sidebar) to the question** I made a post, which can be an answer or a comment.

Is there a way to **avoid this for specific links**?

Often the posted question has little to do with the linked post and the goal is to provide some general info. I want to avoid **"polluting"** the linked question `s **Linked sidebar**.

eg. [Is it ok to link related questions in the comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203653/is-it-ok-to-link-related-questions-in-the-comments/203659)

Now the linked question will have this question in the **Linked sidebar**.

Comment: Use a protocol-relative link (e.g. `//meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122`).

Comment: No, don't do that. I wrote a whole answer on why that's a bad idea, @Sonic. It's a hack, it stands a good chance of breaking in unpredictable ways in the future, and it accomplishes something that you probably shouldn't try to accomplish in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't spend time trying to micromanage the linked sidebar. Yes, it'll get messy for some posts; that's ok - if it grows beyond the space allowed, it'll link to a page with options for sorting. The biggest value is just in *having* the links, both for search engines and for internal recommendations...

That said, [there are ways to link to stuff that won't be recognized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291236/protocol-relative-and-relative-urls-should-be-considered-linked/315223#315223). I don't recommend using them, and certainly don't guarantee that they won't get rewritten at some point in the future, but if you're gonna ignore the advice in my first paragraph then those are the consequences you'll have to accept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get there is no good way. Aside that, why not improve the Linked sidebar, what is the purpose of it... I do not see the necessity of linked questions both ways in the 1st place. I believe it would be an improvement to have the option to exclude linking the latter question to the current.